# Ping Test and save to text file desired Output only

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a very simple .bat file that pings 6 IP Addresses on start up and then pauses the window so I can go through and make sure each is responding.

I was wondering if it would be possible to create an output .txt file that simplifies the results. Instead of an output of something like:

```
C:\Users\>ping 10.127.72.20

Pinging 10.127.72.20 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.127.72.20: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.127.72.20: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.127.72.20: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=61
Reply from 10.127.72.20: bytes=32 time=580ms TTL=61

   Ping statistics for 10.127.72.20:
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
    Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 580ms, Average = 155ms
```

In a .txt file it would only read something like `%servername% 10.127.72.14,  Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)`, for the all 6 IP Addresses in each separate line.

Comment: `ping 10.127.72.20 | FindStr "statistics Packets"` Type `Help`, `ping /?`, `Findstr /?`, and https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.

Comment: I've a list of IP's need to replace list with this code line ?

Comment: You can type it 6 times.

Comment: Use `(for %%I in (10.127.72.20 10.90.3.5) do %SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe %%I | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "statistics Packets")>Results.txt`. Run in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window `for /?` and read the output help. Please next time first search before writing a new question. A Stack Overflow search like [\[batch-file\] ping result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ping+result) lists more than 200 results. So there are really enough similar solutions posted. Please __delete__ your duplicate question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this helped, A quick query, Say i have a device named "A" with IP address 10.127.72.20 and i want in Ping O/p as --- 
Ping statistics for "A" 10.127.72.20:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),  Press any key to ping another address

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick! It gives you the option to enter whatever address you want, so you shouldn't have to change the code to try a different address:

```
@echo off
:begin
cls
echo What address would you like to ping?
echo.
set /p server=Enter the address here: 
cls
ping %server% | findstr /C:"Ping statistics"
ping %server% | findstr /C:"Packets"
echo.
echo Press any key to ping another address>
pause > nul
goto begin
```

Say that you were trying to ping "10.127.72.20", for example. Your output would be:

```
Ping statistics for 10.127.72.20:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Press any key to ping another address
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: you should do the `ping` only once (not for time reasons, but for consistency). `findstr` is able to look for more than one search string: `ping %server% | findstr /C:"Ping statistics" /C:"Packets"`

Comment: Yes, this helped, A quick query, Say i have a device named "A" with IP address 10.127.72.20 and i want in Ping O/p as --- Ping statistics for "A" 10.127.72.20:     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),  Press any key to ping another address